# PdfBox flatten pdf template fields but pdf is still editable

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have a pdf template and with the following code I open it, edit, and then save it with another name after flattening it. But when I open the new pdf file, the fields are still editable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("template.pdf"));
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

    for ( PDField field : acroForm.getFields()) {
        if (field.getFieldType().equals("Tx")) {
            field.setValue(field.getPartialName());
        }
        System.out.println(field.getFieldType());

    }
    acroForm.flatten();
    doc.save("finalFile.pdf");
    doc.close();
}
```

I read other questions about flattening but no one has my problem.
Am I missing anything?

I'm on PDFBox 2.0.12

Comment: please link to your PDF

Comment: As @Tilman's comment implies, the issue most likely is due to a special property of the very PDF you use. Thus, please share it for analysis.